# apt-get stopped working

Tags: apt, packages

I randomly started having trouble using `apt-get` on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspian.  I can remove packages just fine, but when I try to install one, I always get the message

> E: Unable to locate package

The command is run while SSHing into the pi (if that should matter for some reason).

I found lots of things online saying to simply run `apt-get update`, but that doesn't fix it for me. And when I try to install a package that is already up to date, the functionality is as expected. What's going on?

Comment: What package do you want to install? Which version of Raspbian do you run?

Comment: @ThomasWeller this happens for any package I am trying to install.  This is Raspian 4.4.13-v7

Comment: When I started getting issues with `apt-get` I ended up restarting from scratch (new image on new sd card)

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah that's what I ended up doing unfortunately... just hope it doesn't happen again

Comment: It will, because SD cards aren't meant to be used like we use them in Pi's